# Variable Placeholder Ignored

Tags: servicestack

I setup two routes for my service:

```
GET /foo
GET /foo/{Name}
```

The metadata page correctly lists:

```
GET /foo
GET /foo/{Name}
```

But when I browse to `/baseurl/foo/NameValueHere` I get

```
The operation 'NameValueHere' does not exist for this service
```

Am I missing some configuration in my (self-hosted) apphost?

Edit:

Additional information

I didn't like the Route attribute over my DTOs, so I wrote a simple extension method for `IServiceRoutes`.

```cs
public static IServiceRoutes AddFromServiceAttributes(this IServiceRoutes routes)
{
    var myServiceTypes = typeof(MyServiceBase).Assembly.GetDerivedTypesOf<MyServiceBase>();
    var routedMethods = myServiceTypes.SelectMany(type => type.GetMethodsWithAttribute<MyServiceRouteAttribute>());

    foreach (var routedMethod in routedMethods)
    {
        var routesFound = routedMethod.GetAttributes<MyServiceRouteAttribute>();

        foreach (var route in routesFound)
        {
            // request type can be inferred from the method's first param
            // and the same for allowed verbs from the method's name
            // [MyServiceRoute(typeof(ReqType), "/foo/{Name}", "GET")]
            // [MyServiceRoute("/foo/{Name}", "GET")]
            // [MyServiceRoute(typeof(ReqType), "/foo/{Name}")]

            if (route.RequestType == null)
            {
                route.RequestType = routedMethod.GetParameterListFromCache().First().ParameterType;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(route.Verbs))
            {
                var upperRoutedMethodName = routedMethod.Name.ToUpperInvariant();
                route.Verbs = upperRoutedMethodName != "ANY" ? upperRoutedMethodName : null;
            }

            routes.Add(route.RequestType, route.RestPath, route.Verbs);
        }

    }

    return routes;
}
```

I call this method in `AppHost.Configure`, along with `AddFromAssembly`:

```cs
this.SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig { ServiceStackHandlerFactoryPath = "service" });
// some container registrations here
this.Routes.AddFromServiceAttributes().AddFromAssembly();
```

What puzzles me is that the metadata page shows routes correctly.

DTOs are very simple, and they do include the `Name` string property.

```cs
class Foo { public string Name { get; set; } }
```

Edit 2:
I removed the `MyServiceRouteAttribute` attribute and reused ServiceStack's `RouteAttribute`.
Request DTO Types are inferred from 1st method param.

Edit 3: 
Probably I managed to solve this. I was preprending `/json/reply` in the url.

```
http://localhost/service/json/reply/foo/NameValueHere <- not working
http://localhost/service/foo/NameValueHere <- working
```

I thought both the content-type and reply-type tokens were mandatory.

Comment: Any chance your service is listening @ /baseurl/**api**/foo/NameValueHere?

Comment: @MikeP, the service is listening at /baseurl/service: `new EndpointHostConfig { ServiceStackHandlerFactoryPath = "service" }`. /foo?Name=NameValueHere works. The problem seems /foo/{Name}.

Comment: Can you post some of your init, dto, and service code? I'm doing something very similar in a project of my own and it's working without any problems.

Comment: @MikeP - sorry for the delay - I'm going to add more info to the original question.